# How to read input from console in a non blocking way with Go?

Tags: io, go, nonblocking

So I have:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)
//...
var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
str, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

But `reader.ReadString('\n')` is blocking execution. I would like to read input in a non blocking way. Is it possible to achieve non blocking buffered input from `os.Stdin` using `bufio` package or any other std lib package from Go?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general there isn't a concept of non-blocking IO APIs in Go.  You accomplish the same thing by using goroutines.

Here's an example on [Play](http://play.golang.org/p/ayRb7bpQxz), stdin is simulated since play doesn't allow for it.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func(ch chan string) {
        /* Uncomment this block to actually read from stdin
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        for {
            s, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
            if err != nil { // Maybe log non io.EOF errors, if you want
                close(ch)
                return
            }
            ch <- s
        }
        */
        // Simulating stdin
        ch <- "A line of text"
        close(ch)
    }(ch)

stdinloop:
    for {
        select {
        case stdin, ok := <-ch:
            if !ok {
                break stdinloop
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Read input from stdin:", stdin)
            }
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            // Do something when there is nothing read from stdin
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Done, stdin must be closed")
}
```

Comment: It's my first time using goroutines so it took me a while reading the docs to understand what you did. thanks.